# The best overloaded method match for 'string.Contains(string)' has some invalid arguments and Argument '1': cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

Tags: c#, string, sockets, char

```
// 5. Display the received message:

            Console.WriteLine("[Server] Message of client recieved");
            string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"; 
            for (int i = 0; i < totalBytes; i++)

            {
                aChar = Convert.ToChar(incomingDataBuffer[i]);
                Console.Write(aChar);
                if ("aeiouAEIOU".Contains(aChar)) vowels += aChar;
                Console.Write("[Server] Vowel characters deteced: " + vowels);
            }
```

Can't figure out why I keep getting the errors once compiled

Answer (score 3):

string.Contains() wants a string, and you are giving it a char.

Try this instead:

```
if ("aeiouAEUIO".Contains(aChar.ToString())) 
    vowels += aChar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to char[] by [ToCharArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) and than use Contains method. 
You can try something like this with Linq:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "Hello world".ToCharArray();
        var vowels = "aeiouAEIOU".ToCharArray();

        input.Where(c=>vowels.Contains(c)).ToList().ForEach(v=>Console.WriteLine("[Server] Vowel characters deteced: " + v));   
    }
}
```

[.netFilddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7WVeLO)